Which Variables in Angular 17 component Should Be Marked as Signals?
I've recently updated my Angular application to version 17 and came across the new feature called "signals." I've read the general guidelines on using signals for variables that are likely to change frequently, are used in multiple parts of the application, or are exposed to the outside world.
I'm working on a SignInComponent that has various component variables, and I'm trying to determine which ones should be marked as signals to benefit from this new feature effectively. Here's a simplified version of my SignInComponent:
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { appSettings } from '@app/configs';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { ISignInForm } from '../../models';
import { ISignInPayload } from '@shared/models';
import { NgProgress, NgProgressRef } from 'ngx-progressbar';
import { AuthenticationService } from '@core/authentication';
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import {
    FormGroup,
    FormBuilder,
    FormControl,
    AbstractControl
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'sign-in',
    templateUrl: './sign-in.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./sign-in.component.css']
})
export class SignInComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    constructor(
        private _router: Router,
        private _progress: NgProgress,
        private _toastr: ToastrService,
        private _formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private _authService: AuthenticationService
    ) {
        this.initSignInForm();
        this.setCredentailsOnRememberMe();
    }

    public submitted = false;
    public isDisabled = false;
    private progressRef!: NgProgressRef;
    private subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];
    public signInForm!: FormGroup<ISignInForm>;
    private rememberMeKey: string = appSettings.rememberMeKey;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.progressRef = this._progress.ref('progress-bar');
    }

    
    private initSignInForm(): void {
        this.signInForm = this._formBuilder.group<ISignInForm>({
            email: new FormControl('', {
                nonNullable: true,
                validators: [Validators.email, Validators.required]
            }),
            password: new FormControl('', {
                nonNullable: true,
                validators: [Validators.required]
            }),
            rememberMe: new FormControl(false, {
                nonNullable: true
            })
        });
    }

    
    public get formControl(): {
        [key: string]: AbstractControl;
    } {
        return this.signInForm.controls;
    }

    
    public signInOnSubmit(): void {
        this.submitted = true;

        if (this.isDisabled || this.signInForm.invalid) return;

        this.isDisabled = true;
        this.progressRef.start();

        const formValue = this.signInForm.getRawValue();

        

        const payload: ISignInPayload = {
            email: formValue.email,
            password: formValue.password
        };

        this.subscriptions.push(
            this._authService.signIn(payload).subscribe({
                next: (signInResult) => {
                    //Reset flags and complete loading spinner
                    this.submitted = false;
                    this.isDisabled = false;
                    this.progressRef.complete();

                    //Store form values in localStorage if "Remember Me" is checked
                    if (formValue.rememberMe) {
                        localStorage.setItem(
                            this.rememberMeKey,
                            JSON.stringify(formValue)
                        );
                    } else {
                        localStorage.removeItem(this.rememberMeKey);
                    }
                },
                error: (signInError) => {
                    this.submitted = false;
                    this.isDisabled = false;
                    this.progressRef.complete();
                    this._toastr.error(signInError.message);
                }
            })
        );
    }

    

    private setCredentailsOnRememberMe() {
        let rememberMeData!: {
            email: string;
            password: string;
            rememberMe: boolean;
        };
        const storedData = localStorage.getItem(this.rememberMeKey);

        if (!!storedData) {
            rememberMeData = JSON.parse(storedData);
        }

        if (!!rememberMeData && rememberMeData.rememberMe) {
            this.signInForm.patchValue({
                email: rememberMeData.email,
                password: rememberMeData.password,
                rememberMe: rememberMeData.rememberMe
            });
        }
    }


    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.subscriptions.forEach((subscription) => subscription.unsubscribe());
    }
}


